# Emacs highlight variables not prefixed by?

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax-highlighting, major-mode

I'm trying to highlight names like "myname", but not "?myname".  I've used this regex but the highlight includes the preceding characters:

```lisp
("[^\\?[:word:]][[:alpha:]][_[:word:]]*" . font-lock-function-name-face)
```

For example, in "(myname == 1)" the "(" is colored in addition to "myname".

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just `"[[:alpha:]][_[:word:]]*"`?

Character `?` has neither alpha nor word syntax. Same for character `(`.